# How to connect my python code to Qt Creator

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-creator, pyqt5

I want to develop an application using **PyQt5** and **QtCreator**. If I start the application with the IDE, then the desired user interface appears and the buttons react as desired.

However, when I create a `.exe` file in **QTCreator**, the user interface appears, but the **buttons do not respond**. So I assume there is no connection to my Python code after developing the application with **QtCreator**.

How can I **connect my code to the application** so that the buttons react as desired?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sounds like you used the widget designer part of Qt Creator? Or does QtC directly support pyqt project these days? Also, how did you create the .exe? Anyway, as MCVE, I suggest you create a dummy application with just one button, and show us the code, and explain just how you run it under Qt Creator (where it strangely works?), and how you create the .exe (with which it doesn't work?). Please clarify the whole question :-)